# Task with name 'testDebug' not found in project ':module'

Tags: android, junit, gradle, robolectric

As of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0` you can run into `Task with name 'testDebug' not found in project ':module'.`

As in the earlier stage of the build environment it was not possible to test library modules properly using Robolectric & Java this workaround was created:

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
    android.libraryVariants.each { variant ->
        println variant.name
        println tasks
        tasks.getByName("test${variant.name.capitalize()}") {
            dependsOn "assemble${variant.name.capitalize()}"
        }
    }
}
```

With version 1.3.0 this is broken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They have changed the name from `testDebug` to `testDebugUnitTest` hence the code above needs to be changed to:

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
    android.libraryVariants.each { variant ->
        println variant.name
        println tasks
        tasks.getByName("test${variant.name.capitalize()}UnitTest") {
            dependsOn "assemble${variant.name.capitalize()}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that all that changed in 1.3.0? `libraryVariants` in my project is now empty... did something change in how it computes the variants?

Comment: The project you're talking about, which plugin is applied `com.android.application` or `com.android.library`?

Comment: It's `com.android.library`. It turns out `libraryVariants` is seen populated in an afterEvaluate block (previously beforehand as well). Some of my defined settings depend on tasks I generate in the afterEvaluate.

Comment: Yeah okay, could be that they also changed something there, but for me `libraryVariants` is never empty.